# Reset Valuable and repeated action

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am building a game, where the computer makes a patter of four colors and you have to remember the pattern and repeat it.
And it works almost fine, but there is one error which i cant figure out.
When i played a round and lost and the game restarts the level value goes to 2 instead of 1.
And when the new game starts the first two buttons get pressed at the same time.
At the first round everything works fine but the next round not.

```
var gamePattern = [];

var playerPattern = [];

var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]

var level = 0;



$(".btn").click(function () {
    if (patternDone) {
        pressButton(this.id);
        playerPattern.push(this.id);
        checkAnswer();
    }
});

function resetGame() {
    gamePattern = [];
    playerPattern = [];
    gamePattern.length = 0;
    playerPattern.length = 0;
    patternDone = false;
    level = 0;
    $("h1").html("Press A Key to Start")
    $(document).keypress(startGame);
}

//start
$(document).keypress(startGame);


//start Game
function startGame() {
    level = level + 1;
    console.log("level " + level);
    console.log(level);
    gamePattern = [];
    playerPattern = [];
    createLevel();
    console.log(gamePattern)
    playPattern();
    patternDone = true;
    $("h1").html("Level " + level)
}


//play the patter
async function playPattern() {
    for (k = -1; k < level; k++) {
        d = level - k;
        // console.log(gamePattern);
        abcColor = gamePattern[gamePattern.length - d];
        console.log(abcColor);
        await delay(1000);
        pressButton(abcColor);
        d = 0;
    }
}


//create the level
function createLevel() {
    for (y = 0; y <= level; y++) {
        var randomColor = buttonColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * buttonColors.length)];
        gamePattern.push(randomColor);
    }
}

//update h1
function h1Level() {
    levelCopy = level + 1;
    $("h1").html("level " + levelCopy);
}

//pressButton
function pressButton(colord) {
    // console.log(colord);
    animatePress(colord);
    playSound(nameSound = colord);
}

// Sound
function playSound(nameSound) {
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + nameSound + ".mp3");
    audio.play();
}

// animateClick
function animatePress(currentColor) {
    $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
    // console.log(currentColor);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
    }, 100);
}

//delay
const delay = millis => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => resolve(), millis)
});


//Button click and deciding if its right
async function checkAnswer() {
    if (playerPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
        if (playerPattern.join(',') === gamePattern.join(',')) {
            $("h1").html("Correct!");
            console.log("correct");
            await delay(1000);
            startGame();
        } else if (playerPattern.join(',') !== gamePattern.join(',')) {
            $("h1").html("Wrong!");
            level = 0;
            console.log("wrong");
            await delay(3000);
            resetGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of dumping your whole application here for us to debug, try creating a  [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There even may be a chance you resolve your problem doing so!